# RangeError for simple integer assignment in Rails 4.2.0 that should be caught by validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

*** UPDATE: this is now fixed in 4.2.stable and 4.2.1 ***

in Rails 4.2.0 (and current 4.2.stable), the `ensure_in_range` method happens before AR validation, yielding a `RangeError`

if I do something as simple as

```
@obj.threshold = 10_000_000_000
```

on a column with a postgres type integer

```
 threshold  | integer                     |
```

it yields

> RangeError: 10000000000 is out of range for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer with limit 4
>   from .../2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-62e9e61f2d1b/activerecord/lib/active_record/type/integer.rb:41:in `ensure_in_range'

which is true! but tell that to the users. there's an ActiveRecord model validation like

```
  validates :threshold,  presence: true,
    numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than: 1_000_000}
```

i can't imagine this is expected behavior, anyone have any explanation why this type cast happens before validation?

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. Haven't figured out why this is happening.

Comment: The issue is caused by ActiveRecord's built-in typecasting, which is invoked in attribute setters (as you've discovered). Don't know of a way around it off the top of my head, but I'll give it some thought.

Comment: In time of writing this comment only update to `rails 4.2.1` solves this issue, in `4.2.0` I still get `RangeError`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the latest rails version to fix this error, [it was recently fixed by Sean Griffin](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/7c6f3938dee47f0932c2a1d4924adaebc25517ac)

To do that before a version comes out, remove the specific version in your gemfile and use the git location hint :

```
gem 'rails', :git => 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git'
```

Comment: awesome. thanks for the heads up. i was going take more drastic measures on monday. ;)

Comment: Is there a workaround for this, as I keep getting `Could not find gem 'arel (= 7.0.0.alpha) ruby', which is required by gem 'rails (>= 0) ruby', in any of the sources.` when trying `bundle install` with that line.

Comment: @Ryan https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19624. Add this to your Gemfile: gem 'arel', github: 'rails/arel'

Answer (score 2):

You can force your migration file to use a BigInt. I had the same problem but I am not using Rails but just ActiveRecord. This will solve your bug:

`t.integer :really_big_int, limit: 8`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single validation, then upgrading to Rails 4.2.1 does the trick. However, if you've got multiple validations, such as also validating uniqueness, you have to upgrade to a more recent version than 4.2.1. I upgraded to 4.2.3. I don't know whether 4.2.2 works or not.

Comment: In 4.2.3, 4.2.4 doesn't work either: <maxint> is out of range for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer with limit 4

Comment: I limited my "myint" based on Sean Griffin gem mentioned before to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this also happens on simple where(some_id: BIG_NUMBER_HERE). I wouldn't describe it as expected, this should rather result in ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound